# const variable is not binding in Angular 8

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, constants

> Problem

- after binding const variable console.log print NAN.

Angular code

```
      function test() {
        let counter : any = 1;

        fields.forEach(elements => {

          console.log(elements.sub_scenarios.scenario_ + counter);
```

> Output

NAN

This Worked

```
     console.log(elements.sub_scenarios.scenario_1);
```

Fields Array

```
        0:
        code: "type"
        field: "type"
        sub_scenarios:
        scenario_1: {}
        scenario_2: {}
        scenario_3: {}
        scenario_4: {}
```

- i Need to bind number to access object key elements.sub_scenarios.scenario_1
- i tried concat but it didn't work.
- problem occurs to harcode object

  ```
       elements.sub_scenarios.scenario_1
       elements.sub_scenarios.scenario_2
       elements.sub_scenarios.scenario_3

     .... so on
  ```

is suppose if looping 50 object in that case i need to use 50 times if condition then.

Thnaks

Comment: what is output on `fields` objecT?

Comment: try this `fields.forEach(elements => {
    console.log(elements.sub_scenarios['scenario_' + counter]);
})
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

`console.log(elements.sub_scenarios['scenario_' + counter]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate with the sub_scenarios then apply foreach on that array i'e inner loop and incrementing a counter value for each.

```
function test() {
    let counter : any = 1;
    fields.forEach(elements => {

          elements.sub_scenarios.foreach( y => {
              let counter: any = 1;
              console.log(.scenario_ + counter);
              counter++;
});
}}
```